# emacs org mod with math expression

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode, mathjax

I am using org-mod to take note of some of my work, I have recently switched from sublime where I was used to writing some mathjax snippet.

What would be the correct and easiest way of having this snippet rendered correctly (either in the buffer or if not possible, via C-c C-c or C-c C-e).

```
\hat{y} = \hat{\beta}_{0}+\hat{\beta}_{1}x_{1}+\hat{\beta}_{2}x_{2}+...+\hat{\beta}_{p}x_{p}
```

ps : in my .emacs conf file I don't have anything closely related to mathjax or Latex.

Kr,

Comment: When I use source block and mark Latex, after hitting C-c C-c I get the following :

"No org-babel-execute function for Latex!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the latex fragment in `\( ... \)` or `\[ ... \]`and do `C-c C-x C-l` (bound to `org-toggle-latex-fragment`). See the doc string of this function for argument usage.

In recent versions of org, you customize `org-preview-latex-default-process` to set it to the value of the backend you want. You need either dvipng, dvisvgm or ImageMagick as the backend. See also the doc string of the variable `org-preview-latex-process-alist`: it might help explain some things, although you don't have to do anything with it.

If these variables don't exist, you might be using an earlier version of org where the setup is different. If that's the case, then please post which version you are using: `M-x org-version` would tell you.

EDIT: in earlier versions, the function is called `org-preview-latex-fragment` and it's not bound to a key by default. You can call it with `M-x org-preview-latex-fragment` and you can get rid of the preview with `C-c C-c`. The backend setup is different as well: there is support for dvipng and ImageMagick only and the variables are different.

Comment: Enclosing with :  \\[ latex goes here \\] or \\( latex \\) and C-c C-x C-l didn't do anything. "Org-version" prints "Org-mod version 8.2.10 (release_8.2.10 @ /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.5/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/org/)

Comment: Added rudimentary section about earlier versions of org. See if that helps.

Comment: it seems to be working when I call the function org-preview-latex and then export to html, without exporting to html I see no changes at all. That will do the job thank you.

Comment: I'll need to do some testing but my impression was that it should work in the buffer, with no need to export. I'll do some more checking and update the answer.